# OSx pip install awscli

Tags: python, macos, aws-cli

I'm following a tutorial to AWS and I need to install the AWS CLI on my Mac with the following result:

```
sisko$ pip install awscli
Collecting awscli
  Using cached awscli-1.10.63-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docutils>=0.10 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from awscli)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from awscli)
Collecting s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.0 (from awscli)
  Using cached s3transfer-0.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting botocore==1.4.53 (from awscli)
  Using cached botocore-1.4.53-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting colorama<=0.3.7,>=0.2.5 (from awscli)
  Using cached colorama-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyasn1>=0.1.3 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2->awscli)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): futures<4.0.0,>=2.2.0; python_version == "2.6" or python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.0->awscli)
Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 (from botocore==1.4.53->awscli)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 (from botocore==1.4.53->awscli)
  Using cached jmespath-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore==1.4.53->awscli)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, python-dateutil, jmespath, botocore, s3transfer, colorama, awscli
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 736, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 742, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/s4/snsk01z551qdj37bpj3dtzpm0000gn/T/pip-38wpB3-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

**The last section of the output complains about an exception which I know nothing on how to resolve.**

I downloaded and installed Python-3.5.2 but when I execute `python --version` my commandline reports **Python 2.7.10**

Answer (score 3):

I just realised there is provision to surpress that exception with the following:

```
$ sudo pip install awscli --ignore-installed six
```

Issue resolved. Hope this helps others

Comment: I believe it's not recommend to use sudo with pip